# MySQL Query Multiple Joins duplicating data for each row? JIRA Database

Tags: mysql, jira

I'm trying to pull the sum time worked for each user in a certain group over the next 30 days. I am not great at MySQL, so a lot of this may be wrong. This is from a JIRA database.

> ```
>     SELECT DISTINCT cu.display_name AS 'Associate', sum(wl.timeworked/3600) AS '30 Days'
>     FROM worklog AS wl, cwd_user AS cu
>     INNER JOIN cwd_membership AS cm
>         ON cu.directory_id=cm.directory_id
>         AND cu.lower_user_name=cm.lower_child_name
>         AND cm.membership_type='GROUP_USER'
>     INNER JOIN worklog
>         ON worklog.AUTHOR = cu.user_name
>     WHERE cm.lower_parent_name='atl_servicedesk_it_agents' AND wl.STARTDATE BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
>  ORDER BY cu.last_name;
> ```

Right now it just displays the first users name with a sum total of everything in the time worked for everyone. That is obviously not what I want... If I remove the sum from timeworked it shows about half of the users from that group, but each user has a value of 16 hours for timeworked, which is incorrect. Only one user has any value for the next 30 days and it is for 16 hours, so for some reason it is duplicating this information.
Any ideas?

Comment: I you try `GROUP BY cu. display_name` (or better any primary key for user) and place it after the WHERE-clause, and remove `DISTINCT`, does that give any different results?

Comment: Doing that does show all the names now, well 136 of the 367. However, these all still have random times by their names when there should really only be one row because only one user has time logged for the next 30 days. I am unsure if I did the calculation portion wrong with the sum calculating based on anyone's numbers and not just where the names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by taking out the INNER JOINs.

```
SELECT cwd_user.display_name AS 'Associate', sum(worklog.timeworked/3600) AS '30 Days'
FROM worklog, cwd_user,cwd_membership
WHERE worklog.AUTHOR = cwd_user.user_name
and cwd_user.directory_id = cwd_membership.directory_id
and cwd_user.lower_user_name = cwd_membership.lower_child_name
and cwd_membership.membership_type = 'GROUP_USER'
and cwd_membership.lower_parent_name = 'atl_servicedesk_it_agents'
and worklog.STARTDATE BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
GROUP BY cwd_user. display_name
ORDER BY cwd_user.last_name;
```